# comparar dos fechas en php

Tags: php, date

tengo una fecha: `($data->fch_fin_prevista)`  con este formato: `2017-11-29T00:00:00.000Z` y la trasformo de esta forma al formato que yo quiero:

```
 $data->fch_fin_prevista=date('d/m/Y',strtotime($data->fch_fin_prevista));
```

Para que se quede así: `29/11/2017.`

Lo que necesito es poder comparar esta fecha con la fecha actual: `date(d/m/Y)` pero solo me compara el primer dígito.

Comment: ¿Lo que necesitas es saber si una fecha es anterior a otra, por ejemplo? ¿O también necesitas saber la diferencia en días o minutos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza time() para la fecha actual en vez de date(). Haz una resta entre las dos fechas.

```
  $resultado= time() - strtotime($data->fch_fin_prevista);
```

Ya nos dirás si lo conseguiste.

Comment: Gracias pero por alguna razon no funciona, ¿ la comparacion seria usando el simbolo  - ? pensaba que era < o > . Si hago el if usando el - no lo hace bien

Comment: Perdón, no es comparación en sí.
Lo que hace es calcular la diferencia entre las dos fechas no compararla.
Con ese calculo luego tendrías que considerar que quieres que haga según los cálculos obtenidos.